# How to combine similiar classes together or make them into a function?

Tags: python, class, permissions

I am trying to custom different permission classes but I figure, the codes are 95% the same.  If there's a possible way, I really want to make it so they can be combined and called easily.

Let's say I have two different custom permissions

```
class IsUser1(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not request.user.is_anonymous:
            try:
                request.user.user1
                return True
            except Exception:
                return False
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        pass


class IsUser2(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not request.user.is_anonymous:
            try:
                request.user.user2
                return True
            except Exception:
                return False
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        pass
```

Is there an easy and possible way for this?

Comment: what is in request? Are you just trying to find out what user it is? can you show the usage of these classes in context?

Comment: Combine them in what sense? What's your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without really having a better understanding of what you're trying to do, this seems like a possible way you might refactor your code to eliminate code duplication.

It works on the basis that the only variation between the implementations of `has_permission` for `IsUser1` and `IsUser2` is the `user` property they try to access, so I define a common supertype of each class that accepts a callback from each that determines which property it tries to access on received requests.

```
from abc import abstractmethod


class BasePermission(object):
    @abstractmethod
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        pass


class BaseUserPermission(BasePermission):
    def __init__(self, user_selector):
        self.user_selector = user_selector

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not request.user.is_anonymous:
            try:
                self.user_selector(request)
                return True
            except Exception:
                return False
        return False

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        pass


class IsUser1(BaseUserPermission):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(lambda request: request.user.user1)


class IsUser2(BaseUserPermission):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(lambda request: request.user.user2)
```

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that the line `class BasePermission(object):` is relevant for old Python 2 code to force a new style class.  In Python 3 `class BasePermission:` is sufficient.

Comment: @cdarke That's true. Even if it's unnecessary I think it's better style. "Explicit is better than implicit." - Zen of Python.

Comment: @Tagc thx! this is superb, but I am confused a bit how does this part work though? `self.user_selector(request)` how is that passing in the `(lambda request: request.user.user2)`

Comment: @Dora No, the callback is passed to the superclass during construction which is being stored as `self.user_selector`. `self.user_selector(request)` is just invoking that callback with a received request.

Comment: @Tagc ah, I think I understand more now. wish I can find an easy example using JS then I might understand it totally hehe... thx thx